# Codeigniter 2.21 IE Session Issue

Tags: codeigniter, internet-explorer, session

I am having a problem saving session variables using Codeigniter session functions, it works on both chrome and firefox but not on IE, it appears that the session gets cleared out on ajax requests also on page refresh.

Comment: Is it a random phenomenon or is it systematic ? Try to lower `sess_time_to_update` in your config file.

Comment: It was working fine and it suddenly started behaving like this

Answer (score 0):

In your config.php file, set the following to:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession'; //remove underscore
$config['sess_expiration'] = 84200; //increase value from 7200
```